# Referring to generated types in Xtext/Xbase grammar

Tags: xtext, xbase

I am working on an Xtext grammar using Xbase. The grammar permits the user to create a set of Java classes with supertypes from one DSL file. I therefore created a rule like the following:

```
javaClass:
  name=ID ':' supertype=JvmParameterizedTypeReference
```

My generator for the class files works very well as long as the type does not refer to a class file that is being created by the DSL. When a class ClassA is created for example in line 3, and another class ClassB with supertype=ClassA defined in line 4, the parser does not accept the file.

I know this is because ClassA is not a known type when ClassB is parsed, because the generator is started after the whole file have been parsed.

Is it nevertheless possible to solve my problem and enable users to refer to classes that were declared earlier in the same DSL file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you infer a JVM model? It allows first index available classes and then infers JVM models for them when all classes are known. See: https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/305_xbase.html#xbase-inferred-type

Comment: Yes, I am inferring a model. i defined the infer method in the modelInferrer class for the root of this file, which is called after the whole file has been parsed. I tried to additionally define infer methods for each defined class type. That could colve my problem I think, but these infer methods are never called.

Comment: Could you show the code? It could be that you forget `dispatch` keyword. You should call `accept` method on each class to get them indexed.

Comment: I found the problem in the meantime - it seems that the infer method is only called for the topmost element that matches. Once the infer method is called for a node, it will not be called anymore for any contained node. Thank you for your help!